# Can I create directories with dynamic names on run time using os.mkdir()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to download files from the web over several requests. The downloaded files for each request have to be put in a folder with the same name as the request number.

For example:

My script is now running to download files for request number 87665. So all the downloaded files are to be put in the destination folder `Current Download\Attachment87665`. So how do I do that?

What I have tried so far:

```
my_dir = "D:\Current Download"
my_dir = os.path.expanduser(my_dir)
if not os.path.exists(my_dir):
    os.makedirs(my_dir)
```

But it doesn't meet my original requirement. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Not certain what your problem is. You can use `os.path.join` to build paths from strings, for example. Just build your path from various input values as needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just create a path beforehand, via [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
request_number = 82673

# base dir
_dir = "D:\Current Download"       

# create dynamic name, like "D:\Current Download\Attachment82673"
_dir = os.path.join(_dir, 'Attachment%s' % request_number)

# create 'dynamic' dir, if it does not exist
if not os.path.exists(_dir):
    os.makedirs(_dir)
```

Comment: Wowwww.... @miku what a solution you gave here - This is exactly what I was looking for.